# Set a cell to "Yes" or "No" if a range of cells are not empty (have any values)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet with the columns A, B, and C. I wish to have a "Contains Something" column that will either be yes or no depending on if the A, B, or C have **anything** in them. If A, B, or C do not have anything in then a no should be displayed, like this:

```
A     B     C       Contains Something
      10    p       YES
3.5         4       YES
z     zz    zzz     YES
                    NO
f                   YES
      0             YES
                    NO
```

I have tried:

```
=IF(A1:C1,"YES","NO")
```

But I just get `#VALUE!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it with the formula you mention last, you could do it as an array function like so:

```
=IF(A1:C1<>"","YES","NO")
```

Use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` to enter this, curly braces should show around the formula if done correctly.

Otherwise, you'd need a bit of a wordy IF statement, like

```
=IF(AND(A1<>"",B1<>"",C1<>""),"YES","NO")
```

For more information on Array Formulas, see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

Comment: I had no idea about the Ctrl + Shift + Enter! What are the braces for?

Comment: @user9993 Added a link for you to read up on it :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that would implement the style you were going for with the formula in your question:

```
IF(A1&B1&C1="","No","Yes")
```

This concatenates the values and if the result is null, then all of the cells must be empty.